# Kafka API Producer does not write message

Tags: java, eclipse, kafka-producer-api

I try to run this code, but got some issues`

```
public class KafkaProducer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long events = 100;
        Random rnd = new Random();

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("metadata.broker.list", "localhost:9092" );
        props.put("producer.type","async"); // sync
        props.put("serializer.class", "kafka.serializer.StringEncoder");
        props.put("partitioner.class", "kafkaTest.KafkaPartitioner");
        props.put("request.required.acks", "1");
        ProducerConfig config = new ProducerConfig(props);

        Producer<String, String> producer = new Producer<String, String>(config);

        for (long nEvents = 0; nEvents < events; nEvents++) { 
            System.out.println("creating event "+nEvents);
            long runtime = new Date().getTime();  
            String ip = "192.168.2."+ rnd.nextInt(255); 
            String msg = runtime + ",www.om.com," + ip; 
            KeyedMessage<String, String> data11 = new KeyedMessage<String, String>("testt1", ip, msg);
            producer.send(data11);
            //System.out.println(data11);
        }
        producer.close();
    }
}
```

When I launch on sandbox:

```
java -jar testProducer
```

I got

```
Exception in thread "main"
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kafka/producer/ProducerConfig at kafkaTest.KafkaProducer.main(KafkaProducer.java:31)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kafka.producer.ProducerConfig
```

Comment: Please edit your original post and move your comment into the main body.

Comment: You command line seems to be incomplete as well as the exception, please use copy and paste describing all files, directories and content. I would asume you miss at least a Kafka API JAR on your classpath or your application JAR is incomplete. It is not a coding problem at this stage at all. Also show package and imports.

Comment: Hello Eckes. I launch this commande :

Comment: java -cp kafka.jar kafkaTest.KafkaProducer -classPath /root/kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0/libs/kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0.jar